# How do I get out of a server nether portal

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In the sever Mineverse on the mini game survival I decided to go to the nether.  When I walked back into my portal it took me to another portal that had protected blocks surrounding it.  I can't break blocks or place things or go to my inventory or type.  I had to hit control alt delete to get out of minecraft.  How do I get out

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why won't my nether portal bring me back where I left?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/77807/why-wont-my-nether-portal-bring-me-back-where-i-left)

Comment: No I'm stuck in the portal

Comment: I don't care about losing my stuff

Comment: @Thegamer Тry to jump until your hunger bar is depleted (20 jumps per drumstick, saturation needs to be exhausted first, then the hunger bar) and then wait while you starve to death.

Comment: We cannot help you with this problem, this is something you would need to discuss with the administrators of the server

Comment: I tried that I didn't die

Comment: So, if I understand the problem correctly, you are stuck in a nether portal that has protected (presumably Bukkit) blocks around it. Can you go back through the portal into the nether or no?

Comment: No I can't exit the nether portal or I would have gone back

Comment: just saying ive foudn out that people make so much portals that you dont go back to the portal you came from there all wired to different portals

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/59080/are-there-gremlins-in-my-nether-portals?rq=1 something similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you're in a "stuck" situation that will require an admin's intervention to get you out. If `/kill` or starving yourself didn't work then there's a mod disabling this feature. Ask an admin to teleport you out.

Comment: Can you talkwhilestanding in a nether portal?

Comment: No, you'd have to contact an admin using out-of-game means which most communities have.

Comment: That kind of trap is the worst haha

Answer (score 1):

[Why won't my nether portal bring me back where I left?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/77807/why-wont-my-nether-portal-bring-me-back-where-i-left) explains what's going on. I can't say whether the portal was constructed this way on purpose and, if so, whether it was done by admins or griefers.

To escape from the portal, you could kill yourself with /kill but you would, of course, lose all your items. The alternative would be to contact an op or admin and have them teleport you out/ give you permission to break blocks.

Comment: I can't type I clearly stated

Comment: That doesn't help at all

Answer (score -1):

If you are trapped inside a nether portal with protected blocks, your options are VERY limited.

Option 1:  If the server is on hard difficulty, you can jump until you starve.
Option 2: log off and contact the admins.

Comment: I wouldn’t recommend using cheats on a server where it is not allowed.

Comment: While cheating is against the rules of nearly every server, usually setting a nether portal trap of that sort is also against the rules when it's possible.  If a server considers escaping a nether portal trap on your own cheating, it's not somewhere you want to be anyway.