# Why does half of my nether portal lead to a different portal?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In the nether, I have a 3x3 portal. The left side takes me to my base, as I would expect. The right side, however, leads to a completely different portal. Is there a reason it's acting this way?

Comment: See also: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/77807/why-wont-my-nether-portal-bring-me-back-where-i-left

Answer (score 37):

Inside of the game's coding, the nether portal itself is merely a type of block, and the different blocks of the same portal are only connected inasmuch as they were created by the same ring of obsidian.

A nether portal takes you to the nearest available portal in the other dimension (or the one it was originally tied to when it was created), and if there is not one available, one is made. This is tracked by block, and not by portal, so in rare situations, it can create the effect you describe.

Comment: Anything a player can do to "fix" it?

Comment: Lookup for tutorials about "Nether portals linking". By deactivating the right portal and crossing the other the right way, you can force a link between two portals. Be careful of the version your tutorial is for, as linking behavior changed drastically in 1.14

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh as far as I know - destroy your "upper" portal - and build a new one .. (1024 blocks distant from the previous one) - if there is no other nether portal then you get your new nether portal that only connects to this portal .. But its a looong distance in both nether and upper world

Comment: Go to the overworld portal. Press F3 and write down your coordinates. You don't have to be exactly in the portal, you can stand next to it so you won't teleport. Divide the X by 8. Divide the Z by 8. Don't divide the Y. Then go to those coordinates in the nether and build a portal. It will link perfectly to your overworld portal.

Comment: @eagle275 Probably too far away to be practical, and may not generate a portal in the correct location. It's way easier to just ensure the current portals are in the correct coordinates.

Comment: Would moving his overworld portal to the left by ~2 link all portal blocks to the correct netherworld portal?

Comment: Shifting the portal over should work, but to avoid future issues the portals should be lined up correctly.  Otherwise new portals may mess with the linking again.

Answer (score 3):

A Nether portal's target location is determined by the closest portal to the coordinates of the portal converted to the other dimension. However, portal blocks do not have any affinity to the portal they are in and follow the same rules.

For example, if you have a portal in the overworld which streches from 7, 80, 0 to 9, 83, 0 then when you go through on the left side your coordinates will be converted to a different nether position. In this case, X 0, Z 0 vs X 1, 83, Z 0. The closest portal in the other dimension is found using the pythagorean theorem searching a 256 by 256 by 256 area. If you are in the overworld, make sure your portal doesn't have one side in a different chunk to the other and that should fix the problem. If you are in the nether then it may be harder. You can try and get rid of surrounding nether portals but if that is not an option you could try moving the portal to different coordinates where the closest portal is a different one. Another clever solution could be to move the overworld portals in the y coordinates so they are separated. Or make a redstone system to turn on and off the portals when you go through them to stop interference. You can do this by putting a dispenser which drops lava and takes it out quickly so then it will not be reachable but if you go to it, you can light it up with flint & steel.